# c free struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

```
struct trapframe {
      u_int32_t tf_vaddr;     /* coprocessor 0 vaddr register */
      u_int32_t tf_status;    /* coprocessor 0 status register */
      u_int32_t tf_cause;     /* coprocessor 0 cause register */
      u_int32_t tf_lo;
        .....
      u_int32_t tf_hi;
      u_int32_t tf_ra;        /* Saved register 31 */
      u_int32_t tf_at;        /* Saved register 1 (AT) */
      u_int32_t tf_v0;        /* Saved register 2 (v0) */
      u_int32_t tf_v1;        /* etc. */
      u_int32_t tf_epc;       /* coprocessor 0 epc register */
 };

void foo(void *tf, unsigned long as) { 
  struct trapframe *buf_tf = (struct trapframe *)tf; 
  ... }
```

---

In a function foo, I didn't allocate space manually but directly initialize a temp trapframe struct pointer buf_tf with a trapframe struct argument passed in, do I need free the buf_tf manually?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Please show your code. You seem to have mixed struct pointers and struct somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, presumably you have something like this:

```
void myfunc (struct trapframe *p) 
{
    struct trapframe *tf_tmp = p;

    ...
}
```

In this case the memory is allocated in the caller, it is the caller's struct you are accessing.  You are in no position to free that. You don't know where it is allocated (heap or stack), and the caller might wish to access it later.

or maybe:

```
void myfunc (struct trapframe tf) 
{
    struct trapframe *tf_tmp = &tf;

    ...
}
```

In this case the struct is passed by copy and is placed on your function's local stack (although implementation details vary).  It will be freed when the current functions exits.

So no, don't try to free it.  Doing so might well  break other things!  Executing `free` on an object that was not allocated on the heap can have bad effects that are *undefined*.

Comment: Yes, struct trapframe * tf should be used by caller function, so I cannot free tf via buf_tf in the function foo.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) No , if you don't need to free it if you don't have to free `trapframe struct argument passed in`
2) Yes, if you have to ultimately free the `trapframe struct argument passed in`